# Why can't my non-master node fetch indices from the master in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been working on setting up an ELK stack for work. So far, everything's gone swimmingly, so I'm now tackling the next part of my setup: creating a cluster.

I made the configuration file changes (below) to turn my single node into a cluster master:

```
elasticsearch.yml (master)
cluster.name: skunkworks
node.name: node-1
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: _non_loopback:ipv4_
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "<IP of slave server deleted>"]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

Then I restarted the master node. I then set up elasticsearch on the slave node with the following configuration:

```
elasticsearch.yml (slave)
cluster.name: skunkworks
node.name: node-3
node.master: false
node.data: true
network.host: _non_loopback:ipv4_
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<IP of master server deleted>", "127.0.0.1"]
discovery.zen.fd.ping_retries: 20
discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout: "1m"
```

Then I started up the slave machine. Checking the kopf plugin on the master node, I can see that node-3 has joined the cluster. One of the unassigned shards is being allocated to the slave. This never finishes (nor even starts).

Checking my slave's data directory, I can see that the directory for the cluster/node has been created, but there's no trace of the index.

Checking logs on my slave node, I see the following:

```
[2016-01-20 20:39:58,954][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [node-3] [indices:monitor/stats] failed to execute operation for shard [[logstash-2016.01.20][0], node[c2IE_LtZQGSVPoaFyqvPlA], [R], v[9], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=Ap12JxKSS-mHHchnwaLWCw], unassigned_info[[reason=NODE_LEFT], at[2016-01-20T20:03:11.455Z], details[node_left[0N9oUHcrRT6i-DD5VX2BeQ]]]]
[logstash-2016.01.20][[logstash-2016.01.20][0]] BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[operation indices:monitor/stats failed]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no such index];
```

...and...

```
[2016-01-20 20:39:48,822][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [node-3] [indices:monitor/stats] failed to execute operation for shard [[.kibana][0], node[c2IE_LtZQGSVPoaFyqvPlA], [R], v[9], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=yk8xq3SGSOquHXcY_Ouy3Q], unassigned_info[[reason=NODE_LEFT], at[2016-01-20T20:03:11.455Z], details[node_left[0N9oUHcrRT6i-DD5VX2BeQ]]]]
[.kibana][[.kibana][0]] BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[operation indices:monitor/stats failed]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no such index];
```

...repeated ad nauseum.

I've checked with telnet to make sure that I can reach each node from the other and that all ports are open. node-3 doesn't have any data in its data directory, which I thought was going to be filled up with the master's.

From the NODE_LEFT exception, I'd assume that node-3 got kicked out of the pool... but node-1 sees it until I shut down elasticsearch on node-3 (at which point, there's a log line with the disconnect status).

Does anyone have an idea of why my cluster forms but the slave node won't accept data?

**Update:** If I do a health check on my slave node, it returns a `master not found` error. Which seems quite reasonable to me, except that the master can theoretically see it.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time digging around with the log levels turned up to DEBUG, which is what I should have done in the first place. I had previously installed shield on my master node but then had deleted it before setting up a cluster in order to reduce the number of variables I was juggling. However, I had not gotten rid of the license plugin directory.

As a result, my master kept erroring out when communicating with my slave but it wasn't showing up at the INFO level. Removing the license directory completely eliminated the problem.